# Help with JS setInterval, it goes crazy sometimes!

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Hey guys.  I have having a bit of trouble with this script I wrote regarding setInterval.  It sometimes just goes crazy and starts firing repeatly even before the interval time has hit.

Basically I have this slider and I want it to slide automatically at intervals and this is the script I have but like I said it goes crazy have a little bit. What am I doing wrong?

```
var current = 1;
function autoAdvance()
{
    if(current === -1) { return false; }

    jQuery('#slide_menu ul li a').eq(current%jQuery('#slide_menu ul li a').length).trigger('click',[true]); 
    current++;
}
var itvl = setInterval(function(){autoAdvance();},8000);
```

Comment: @Box9-what other code do you need to see?  This is all there is for the interval function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setInterval (as with setTimeout) adds the callback function onto the event queue when the timeout expires - if there is other event handling happening at the same time, this can lead to multiple queued callbacks. I prefer to use setTimeout and have the callback function schedule another timeout. This way you will only schedule the next call once the previous one has completed.

```
function callback(){
    setTimeout(callback,8000);
}
setTimeout(callback,8000);
```

Oh, also, there is no need to wrap autoAdvance in a function in your setInterval.

```
setTimeout(autoAdvance,8000);
```

Comment: @jordancpaul-i was afraid you would say to use setTimeout.  However, I actually played with it for 2 hours trying to convert my code to use setTimeout but it just didn't work...any help appreciated. Oh and if I don't wrap them in a function, i will get a not defined error.

Comment: That suggests that there are other problems going on here. What exactly is the not defined error that you are getting?

Comment: @jordancpaul-it will give me "autoAdvance" is not defined if i change it to var itvl = setInterval('autoAdvance()',8000);

Comment: two things to try. There are subtleties that can be confusing when using function declarations `function fnName()` instead of function assignments `var fnName = function()`. Since this is likely a snippet of other code, it is impossible for me to tell if there are, definitely, problems but I would suggest trying a function assignment. Also, try `setInterval(autoAdvance,8000)` (notice, no quotes and no parenthesis)

Comment: Yeah no quotes and parenthesis works...now let me try to convert it again to settimeout...thanks again!